# Using variable after forward >>

Tags: cmd

I would like to get output to `aa.txt` file:

```
SET AAA=aa.txt
dir >> AAA
```

But got to `AAA` file.

How to solve this?

Comment: `dir >> %AAA%`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell needs to be told that the file name is the contents of the AAA variable and not "AAA" itself.

```
SET "AAA=aa.txt"
DIR >>"%AAA%"
```